# Error is coming after switching from chromedriver 116 to 117 only when running remotely

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I'm using Selenium Web driver 3.141.0 and chromedriver 117.0.5938.88 on the VM and the following error received during the test execution. I did not face this issue until we switched from chromedriver 116 to 117. Also, this issue is not happening in my local PC.

```
20-09-2023 15:28:12.756 | ERR | OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51951/session/ed822b3b02fa5ad142a4dd768e5dd8e8/element/3E16DC2127B2C1236A86C156831345F3_element_25969/click. The status of the exception was UnknownError, and the message was: An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
---> System.Net.WebException: An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
```

I tried to run the same test on my local PC and I was able to run it without receiving this error

Comment: Does switching back make the error go away?

Comment: Also: run again with verbose logging enabled on ChromeDriver? See: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/logging

Comment: I ran again with verbose logging and it gave me this log at the time it encountered this error
[1695273077.394][WARNING]: Processing messages while being disconnected

Comment: Just to let you know that I faced the same issue when chrome is updated from 116 to 117, but i am using the wedriver version 4.13.1

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @DilshanKay I added an exception handler that if the driver disconnects, i connect it again and resume the script from the same place.